# Empty space under my main page footer - Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, footer, space

I have a weird problem,

My main page (Only) is showing long empty space under page footer and this happens when I use Google Chrome only.
IE, Firefox working without any problems.

PS :
1 - this weird space disappears from Google Chrome when i turn my homepage to static content page.

2 - I've tried to disable all plugins but still have the same problem

So how to solve this problem.?

[Site URL](http://agyadinternational.com/style/)

Comment: Please post the relevant code in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the `.screen-reader-text` class inside each `article` which is keeping the items inside the main page flow.

Try updating the css to:

```
.says, .screen-reader-text {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Just keep in mind that this will also affect the `.says` class. If needed, just move `.screen-reader-text` into its own class.

```
.says {
      clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
      height: 1px;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: absolute !important;
      width: 1px;
}
.screen-reader-text {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 1px;
      height: 1px;
      overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but when i used your solution I've got a vary wide page to the left, Check the URL again.

Comment: Sorry, my browser wasn't displaying the left scroll. Try just changing `left` property on .screen-reader-text to `0`. I'll update the answer to reflect.

Comment: Really awesome, you saved my life, Really Thanks.